# Does the user who executes a stored procedure which contains a delete query need delete permission?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

Or do they need to be granted to delete a record from a table only when they execute a query which is not a stored procedure?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Does the user who executes a stored procedure which contains a delete query need delete permission?

No, and that's one of the reasons you can abstract such operations into a stored procedure.
All the user needs is `EXEC` permission granted on the stored procedure. This is because the author of the stored procedure is assumed to have allowed only valid cases of deleting the records from the table.

> do they need to be granted to delete a record from a table only when they execute a query which is not a stored procedure

Right, they need `DELETE` permissions on the table to delete a record using `DELETE` DML operation.

Comment: In SQL Server, this is true if the owner of the stored procedure is also the owner of the table.  See Ownership Chaining.